# Performance evaluation of two models by bayesian forecasting

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose I have a model f(y|r) which I estimate by two datasets (dataset A and dataset B) where "r" is the parameter(s) . In Bayesian framework, we can sample the parameters from the whole posterior distribution P(r|y).

Now suppose for each case (case 1: model estimated using dataset A; case 2: model estimated using dataset B), we take 1000 sample of parameters from the posterior distribution P(r|y). To forecast from future, we simulate events from the posterior predictive distribution using each of the 1000 parameter samples from posterior distribution and finally average over them.

The plot of the events forecasted by case 1 (model A) and case 2 (model B) along with true values is like:

[image]

But this is only graphical way to see which model gives closer values to actual true values, that is, which model forecasted better. I want to know if there is any evaluation technique to find which model gives better forecasting?

Comment: how about for each n.events you compute the difference between each model and the truth, square those differences than make a mean, under square root. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation

Comment: @RLave , thanks for the suggestion. But is it the only way? I want to know if there's any conventional way to evaluate the forecasting performance of two models.

Comment: with forecast usually you use MAPE or MAE

Comment: @RLave I suppose you are talking about parameter estimates. I wanted to know about forecasted events.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but I was referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error

Comment: @RLave I thought it was Maximum A Posteriori Estimate (MAPE).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion :)